# Error "InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type." While using Instantiate in Unity

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

Okay, so I'm making a 2D game in unity, and when I run the code, I get this error:

```
InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
ToastSpawn.spawnToast () (at Assets/Scripts/ToastSpawn.js:11)
```

The code in the file ToastSpawn.js is as follows:

```
#pragma strict

var Toast : Rigidbody;
var ToastSpawner : GameObject;

function Start() {
    InvokeRepeating("spawnToast", 3, 1);
}

function spawnToast() {
    var toastClone = Instantiate(Toast, GameObject.Find("ToastSpawner").transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    toastClone.AddForce(Vector2 (0,1) * 1000);
}
```

I just started using unity yesterday, so that is probably why I am getting this error. :)

Comment: FYI You need to forget about "javscript" and use only c#.  Unity are removing javascript soon; also c# is actually far easier.  Forget javascript, use only c#

Comment: This site is **just not suitable** for extremely simple questions about "how to use variables" and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it'd be better if you take start from C# :P Although I am not a JavaScript guy but still can see some glitches.

- You are instantiating Rigidbody actually instead of GameObject. Take GameObject instead of only Rigidbody, then getComponent of Rigidbody from that object in order to apply force.
- You have ToastSpawner as GameObject so why or you using GameObject.Find? Just that same GameObject.

Something like,

```
var Toast : GameObject;
var ToastSpawner : GameObject;
...
... 
var toastClone = Instantiate(Toast, ToastSpawner.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
var rb : Rigidbody = toastClone.GetComponent("Rigidbody");
rb.AddForce(...);
```

Comment: I have applied this to my code and now I am getting this error:  `Assets/Scripts/ToastSpawn.js(13,8): BCE0019: 'AddForce' is not a member of 'UnityEngine.Component'.`  The code is here:  `#pragma strict

var Toast : GameObject;
var ToastSpawner : GameObject;

function Start() {
    InvokeRepeating("spawnToast", 3, 1);
}

function spawnToast() {
    var toastClone = Instantiate(Toast, Vector3 (0,-2,0), Quaternion.identity);
    var rb = toastClone.GetComponent("Rigidbody");
    rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * 1000);
}`

Comment: That's why I hate javascript. Replace `var rb = toastClone.GetComponent("Rigidbody");` to `var rb : Rigidbody= toastClone.GetComponent("Rigidbody");`. Check the edited answer

Comment: Last night I decided that I was going about moving the toast wrong, so I made a new script to handle the AddForce() function. :P It works great now, after I adapted your answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use [Object.Instantiate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) on a Rigidbody typed object (Toast : Rigidbody), which is a component, not a GameObject. A component can only be added to an existing GameObject using [GameObject.AddComponent](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html). You need to create a prefab for your Toast item (this prefab has a Rigidbody component on it) and use the prefab in the Instantiate method.

Also, you shouldn't use capital letter on attribute's names.

Comment: I have a prefab for Toast. How do I use it with instantiate?

Comment: There is a Unity script exemple in the Unity documentation here : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Set your variable public to link the prefab through the inspector and then use it in the Instantiate function.